# can we remove few entity property only for Get operation, not for POST,PUT

Tags: asp.net-web-api, entity-framework-6, odata

I am able to ignore the property like below in `webapiconfig.cs` file for get method.

`builder.EntitySet<Table1>("Table1").EntityType.Ignore(e => e.ABC);
builder.EntitySet<Table1>("Table1").EntityType.Ignore(e => e.DEF);`

but I don't want to ignore the above property for `PUT/POST` operation.

how to acheive this?
Is there any way to dynamically do this as per `GET/PUT/POST` operation request?

I am working with `OData` web API.

Comment: Yes, use a DTO for the get operation.

Comment: i am using DTO for get, but that is not OData Complaince. means its not giving the child data for $expand query.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, Using Data Transfer Objects (DTOs) we can achieve this.

Please refer the below web page.

[Here we have the examples](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5)